# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortImpl] and Servlet

Tags: glassfish

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V11]
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.descriptor.WebBundleDescriptorImpl.addWebComponentDescriptor(WebBundleDescriptorImpl.java:396)
    at org.glassfish.webservices.connector.annotation.handlers.WebServiceHandler.processAnnotation(WebServiceHandler.java:473)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.factory.SJSASFactory$LazyAnnotationHandler.processAnnotation(SJSASFactory.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:350)
    ... 59 more

Comment: You need to add enough information so that someone can repeat your problem and answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the first line of the error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Servlet [RegistrationRequesterPortImpl] and Servlet [RegistrationPortImpl] have the same url pattern: [/RegistrationService_V11]

Both **RegistrationRequesterPortImpl.java** and **RegistrationPortImpl.java** have the same URL pattern (`/RegistrationService_V11`). You need to change the URL pattern for one of these.

Comment: can you tell me how do that i use intellij idea

Comment: I'm not sure how I can make it clearer...look in the class files in the answer and change the URL pattern, assuming they are set in annotations. If not, look in the web.xml files for each class.